# Form with dynamic choices won't set choice as selected when bound

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this form where one of the fields ("wheels") has a dynamically generated list of choices:

```
class CarForm(forms.Form):
    colour = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(("BLACK", "Black"), ("YELLOW", "Yellow")))
    wheels = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["wheels"].choices = [(_, _) for _ in range(4)]
```

When I bind the form with data, Django does not set the choice for the field with the dynamic choices to "selected":

```
f = CarForm({"colour": "YELLOW", "wheels": 2})
f.is_valid()
Out[10]: True
f.as_p()
Out[11]: '''
    <p>
        <label for="id_colour">Colour:</label>
        <select name="colour" id="id_colour">
            <option value="BLACK">Black</option>
            <option value="YELLOW" selected>Yellow</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="id_wheels">Wheels:</label>
            <select name="wheels" id="id_wheels">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2" selected>2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
    </p>
'''
```

I guess that's because the form's `__init__` method is called before the choices are set, but I have to call `__init__` first, otherwise the method complains with an `AttributeError: 'CarForm' object has no attribute 'fields'`

I want to show the form with the user's input to the user so that they can see the result of their request and adapt accordingly. It's not very user friendly if the selections they made are not reflected in the form.

How can I fix this?